# Update css settings with an object received

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, background

I am trying to modify my css with settings which I received from an object.
I send the object after the user select the options from a form.
Now I want to use this to change my layout, but I don't know exactly how.

My template looks like this

```
div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showMenu()">Layout Settings</div>
<div ng-show="themeSelected">
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Background color for views</label>
                    <input type="text" name="background_color" id="background_color" ng-model="selectedLayout.background_color" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Background image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="background_image" id="background_image" ng-model="selectedLayout.background_image" class="form-control" style="width:25%" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Buttons color</label>
                    <input type="text" name="buttons_color" id="buttons_color" ng-model="selectedLayout.buttons_color" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Buttons size</label>
                    <input type="text" name="buttons_size" id="buttons_size" ng-model="selectedLayout.buttons_size" class="form-control" placeholder="13px" style="width:5%" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Buttons font color</label>
                    <input type="text" name="buttons_font_color" id="buttons_font_color" ng-model="selectedLayout.buttons_font_color" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Headers size</label>
                    <input type="text" name="headers_size" id="headers_size" ng-model="selectedLayout.headers_size" class="form-control" placeholder="13px" style="width:5%" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Headers color</label>
                    <input type="text" name="headers_color" id="headers_color" ng-model="selectedLayout.headers_color" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Info size</label>
                    <input type="text" name="info_size" id="info_size" ng-model="selectedLayout.info_size" class="form-control" placeholder="13px" style="width:5%" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Info font color</label>
                    <input type="text" name="info_font_color" id="info_font_color" ng-model="selectedLayout.info_font_color" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveChanges(selectedLayout)">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <div style="color: red" ng-show="errors.length > 0">{{errors}}</div>
</div>
```

And when I press Save button all those defined above are in an object. Now I want to use those settings to actually change my layout.
This is my controller where i defined the saveChanges

```
'use strict';

(function () {
    angular.module('routerApp').controller('LayoutController', function ($scope,layoutRepository) {
        $scope.showMenu = function() {
            $scope.themeSelected = true;
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $scope.themeSelected = false;
        };

        $scope.saveChanges = function (selectedLayout) {
            layoutRepository.saveLayoutInfo(selectedLayout);
            $scope.themeSelected = false;
        };
        $scope.selectedLayout = {};

        window.model = $scope.selectedLayout;
    });
}());
```

This is the layoutRepository

```
'use strict';

(function () {
    angular.module('routerApp').factory('layoutRepository', function ($http) {
        return {
            saveLayoutInfo: function (selectedLayout) {
                console.log(selectedLayout);
                $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/api/LayoutSettings",
                    data: selectedLayout,
                    cache: false
                });
            }
        };
    });
}());
```

Comment: Can you break it down for us. `buttons_color`. The part before the underscore, does this refer to a class name?

Comment: I edit the post, to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. It will take your data, retrieve the classnames, keys and values from it and appends it to the correct element:

```
    var data = data.split("\n"); //split the received data on a new line
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var className = data[i].substr(0, data[i].indexOf("_")); //classname = part before the "_"
        var csskey = data[i].substr(data[i].indexOf("_")+1, data[i].indexOf(":");
        var cssvalue = data[i].substr(data[i].indexOf(":")+1).trim().replace("\"",""); strip whitespaces and quotations
       loadCSSIntoControl(className, {key:csskey, value : cssvalue });
    }

function loadCSSIntoControl(classname, css)
{
     if (css.key == "size")
     {
         css.key = "font-size";
     }
     //iterate over all elements using Array.prototype.map
     Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("."+classname), function(elem) {
           elem.style[css.key.replace("_", "-")] = css.value; //replace underscore with dash
     });
}
```

> **Note**: if the first part isn't a class name, you can easily change this to another type of selector.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the settings to a scope (are they an object/json? Your output seems odd)

```
<button data-ng-style="{
    background: selectedLayout.buttons_color,
    color: selectedLayout.buttons_font_color,
    fontSize: selectedLayout.buttons_size
}">Button</button>
```

This is assuming the data looks like this:

```
selectedLayout = {
    buttons_color: "rgb(83, 255, 0)",
    buttons_font_color: "rgb(255, 247, 0)",
    buttons_size: "11px",
    headers_color: "rgb(187, 52, 202)",
    headers_size: "18px",
    info_font_color: "rgb(17, 15, 15)",
    info_size: "12px"
}
```

Comment: If i put it that way, only the color of that button is changing, but i want all the buttons on the page to have that color.

Comment: Then they'll all need the the same ng-style

Comment: Yes, but this will stay only on this page from the project, i want all the project to have this properties.

Comment: Look into creating css via javascript.